# Insert taxonomy term to different table

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have different table in the database called "wp_taxterms". How do I insert to that table every time a news taxonomy term under "Clients" is created or if an existing one has been updated/deleted?

EDIT:

```
    if( isset($_GET['page']) && ($_GET['page']=="export-clients") ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_special");   
        $categories = get_terms( 'clients' );

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Clients.csv\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        //create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        //output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Address', 'Email', 'Contact'));

        foreach($categories as $cat) {
            fputcsv($output, array($cat->name, $cat->description, $cat->email, $cat->contact) );            
        }   

        fclose($output);
        exit;
    }//endif
```

Comment: `I have different table in the database called "wp_taxterms"` - why?

Comment: Because I need to export the taxonomy terms to CSV. `get_terms` is not working..

Comment: What do you mean `get_terms` is not working? I'm pretty sure you'd be better off solving that than trying to pull terms into another table just to export.

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, the foreach loop only loops twice even if I have 3 items under "clients"

Comment: You could try replacing `$categories = get_terms( 'clients' );` to `$categories = get_terms( 'clients', array('hide_empty' => false) );`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

For example, if you don't override the `hide_empty` argument, it will only retrieve terms that are attached to at least one post.

As for your code, there are no `email` and `contact` properties for a `$term` object. And why `$result = ...` if you're not using it anywhere?

Comment: All my terms are attached to at least one post. The `$result` is just a past attempt..